# Swap values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, self-join

```
Before:

Box_Num.     Value
  1.          100
  5.          500
```

---

```
After:

Box_Num.     Value
  1.          500
  5.          100
```

I want to swap the values with each other as shown above. It should not matter what the value is. I want a simple SQL statement which swaps the value field of Box 1 and Box 5.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, Postgres...?

Comment: `UPDATE YourTable SET value = CASE WHEN Box_Num = 1 THEN 500 ELSE 100 END  WHERE Box_Num IN (1,5)`

Answer (score 1):

> I want a simple SQL statement which swaps the value field of Box 1 and Box 5.

How about a self-join?

```
select t1.box_num, t2.value
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.box_num <> t.boxnum
where t1.box_num in (1, 5) and t2.box_num in (1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ then you can use a join-like `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Value = t.Value
FROM (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Box_Num IN (1, 5)) AS t
WHERE tablename.Box_Num IN (1, 5) AND tablename.Box_Num <> t.Box_Num
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/addfa/2).
Results:

```
Box_Num   Value
1         500
5         100
```